# Difference between .join() and .has() / .any() in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, join, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, rdbms

*Designing a smarter query method.* The query designed for retrieving purposes at the moment is:

```
query_retrieve = self.session.query(Assessment_Result).\
            filter(Assessment_Result.owner.has(User.username == owner)).\
            filter(Assessment_Result.assessment.has(Assessment.name == assessment)).one()
```

which makes use of SQLAlchemy's `EXISTS` keyword. This works when running `nosetests`, but becomes problematic later on. I need to design a better query method using a `.join()` that does the same type of comparison and returns `.one()`. More importantly, I want to better understand why the `.join()` method is an effective method for querying.

I have spent some time trying to breakdown the SQLAlchemy docs and found the following information useful, but could use more assistance in designing a query method using `.join()` and why it is better. 
[Versions: Python 2.7.9 and SQLAlchemy 1.0.9]

Based on the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins):

`Query.join()` The recommended form:

> If there were no foreign keys, or several, Query.join() works better
>   when one of the following forms are used:
>
> ```
> query.join(Address, User.id==Address.user_id)    # explicit condition
> query.join(User.addresses)                       # specify relationship from left to right
> query.join(Address, User.addresses)              # same, with explicit target
> query.join('addresses')                          # same, using a string
> ```

Boolean operators: `.has()` and `.any()` (my code above)

> The EXISTS keyword in SQL is a boolean operator which returns True if
>   the given expression contains any rows. It may be used in many
>   scenarios in place of joins, and is also useful for locating rows
>   which do not have a corresponding row in a related table.

Table design:

```
class Assessment_Result(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'assessment_results'

    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    owner = relationship('User', backref='assessment_result')

    assessment_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('assessments.id'))
    assessment = relationship('Assessment', backref='assessment_result')
```